# Flask error when use decorator roles_required in flask route

Tags: python, flask, roles

I have a blueprint registered with its own routes, in that routes i need validate the user's role with @roles_required decorator imported from flask-user library
I can log in, but when i need to access to that route i got an Attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_manager'
```

I removed the decorator and the page render well.

The models are:

```
user_roles = db.Table('user_roles',
          db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
          db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)


class User(CRUDMixin, UserMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                   primary_key = True
                   )

    username = db.Column(db.String(64),
                         index=False,
                         unique=True,
                         nullable=False
                         )
    password = db.Column(db.String(64),
                         index=False,
                         nullable=False
                        )
    email = db.Column(db.String(80),
                      index=True,
                      unique=True,
                      nullable=False
                      )
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),
                        index=False,
                        unique=False,
                        nullable=False
                        )
    bio = db.Column(db.Text,
                    index=False,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=True
                    )

    # Relationsihp with role table
    # To get the roles of an user: User.permission.all()
    # To get the users of a role: Role.users
    roles = db.relationship('Role',
                            secondary=user_roles,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic')
                            )

    def __rep__(self):
        return f"<User>('{self.username}', '{self.email}'')"

    def __init__(self, name, email, username, password, bio=''):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.set_password(password)
        self.bio = bio
        self.created = datetime.datetime.now()

    class Role(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'role'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(),
                   primary_key=True
                   )
    name = db.Column(db.String(50),
                     unique=True
                     )
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),
                        index=False,
                        unique=False,
                       )

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.created = datetime.datetime.now()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role {}>'.format(self.name)
```

The route is defined like this:

```
from flask_user import roles_required

@myblueprint.route('/')
@roles_required(['admin', 'editor'])
def index_publications():
    return "This is my publications page.", 200
```

As i said, to the the message "This is my publications page" i need to remove the decorator, instead i got the AttributeError from Flask.

Comment: Your app is not well configured. See the quickstart of flask-user for reference: https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart_app.html

Comment: I see, i defined the user_manager from flask-user, so, it defines login, and logout methods views, that i already have, so it renders its own forms with its own authentication method. Is there any way to use my endpoints with my form?. Thanks

Comment: If you read the docs, you will find what is possible. See: https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_forms.html and https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_user_manager__views.html

Comment: I have this problem too, How could you resolve this?

Comment: Yes, according to @Hildeberto i need to define the user_manager.